# Can this question be improved to get it reopened?

Tags: discussion

I'm talking about [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86325)

First, a disclaimer: I have the best answer at this point, and I heavily edited the question, so do take my opinions with a pinch of salt.

I think that the original wording of the question was not very good, but the general idea of the question is in my opinion pretty interesting.

The question may be thought as of broad, as it does not talk about a specific genre, but I think it is specific enough on the topic of difficulty (as in, how to design difficult games).

I think the answer I provided offers good advice regardless of the game genre, and I would really like to invite for more answers. This is a topic that fascinates me, and it saddens me to find so few interesting and fun questions regarding game level design.

I edited the question, and it has gotten 3 reopen votes at this point. The question itself has 12 upvotes and 1 downvote, so I would like to ask you guys to either vote to reopen it, or help me improve the question to get it reopened.

Additionally, I would like to ask moderator Josh Petrie why he thought the question needed to be closed as a moderator action, even though one of the close-voters (Anko) did not provide a comment to support his vote, and the other close-voter (Krom Stern) provided an answer himself, and was pretty supportive of the answer I gave. To be honest, I was expecting the close votes to age by themselves as the question had improved from its original form.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real general solution to the problem so it's useless to ask a general question in my opinion. For example the highest votes answer of Panda Pajama says almost nothing about difficulty of adventure games or role playing games. So you read all the answers and then you didn't learn anything about the things you might be interested in.

I think reducing the scope of the question is the way to go and this was proposed to the questioner but he didn't like that much.

As it is most answers are about difficulty of action games. So why not reducing the question to action games or the likes?